# A question about how far a well known theorem of Sierpinski can be strengthened

Tags: general-topology

Let E be a finite dimensional Euclidean space. A well known theorem of Sierpinski states that if C is an infinite compact-i.e. closed and bounded-connected subset of E, then C cannot be the countable union of pairwise disjoint closed subsets of E. I have also seen a theorem of Hausdorff which implies that the same conclusion continues to hold if C is any infinite closed connected subset of E-not necessarily compact-provided C is locally connected. My question is: Does Hausdorff's theorem continue to hold, if one drops the requirement that C should be locally connected?..........Some of the statements I have read in the literature seem to suggest that the answer is "Yes" whenever the infinite connected subset C of E is locally compact. This will certainly be the case if E is a finite dimensional Euclidean space and C is a closed subset of E. But I am not really clear about the whole situation.

Comment: I don't have time now to look into this, but I suggest googling [Sierpinski "Un théorème sur les continus"](https://www.google.com/search?q=Sierpinski+%22Un+th%C3%A9or%C3%A8me+sur+les+continus%22). For instance, I found [this](http://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1984-091-01/S0002-9939-1984-0735581-2/) and [this](https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.rmjm/1181072797) right away.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sierpinsky himself constructed an example of a closed connected subset of $R^3$ which is a countable union of pairwise disjoint closed nonempty subsets.

W. Sierpinski, Sur guelgues proprietes topologiques du plan, Fund. Math. 4 (1923), 1-6.

Comment: This is the answer I was looking for.  It shows that additional conditions on C besides being closed in E are needed, in order for Sierpinski's conclusion to follow.